# React Native - Deep linking from Google app in iOS not working

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I noticed that my app does not open when tapping on a link from the result page of the Google Search app on iOS.

I have configured Universal links for iOS and Android.

Works well as expected on **Chrome and Safari browsers**. But not on the `Google.app`.

I tried to search for a facebook profile on the 'Google Search app' and tapped on a result. It actually navigated into the web page (profile), and then opened the native Facebook app (depplinked into the profile page).

So I was wondering what I had missed. Was it a `<meta />` tag that was missing on the web page? `Eg. in https://www.example.com/item/123`

Or something I need to add in the Xcode configurations?

#### Example scenario:

```
Domain    - https://www.example.com
Bundle Id - com.example.app
Link      - https://www.example.com/item/123
```

```
// Xcode => Associated Domains => Domains

applinks:www.example.com
```

```json
// File: apple-app-site-association

{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "XYZXYZX.com.example.app",
                "paths": [
                    "/item/*"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "components": [
            {
                "/": "/item/*"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

#### Versions:

```
react: 16.13.1
react-native: 0.63.3
react-navigation: ^4.4.3
react-native-branch: ^5.0.1
```

[image: Google ap]

Comment: Can you share a sample Branch Link which you are using?

Comment: @KartikShandilya The branch links work fine actually. It's just when we tap on a search result on Google app (which are normal links), it doesn't deep link into the app. :/

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem. Seems we need some configuration on React.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue here in react native 2021 the tutorials are very old the link does not open my app only opens as a search term or website

Comment: @Janaka Oh nah, couldn't find any solution unfortunately. :(